# C# (Xml) Attributes to Elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have the xml file with attributes but I need to use elements instead of attributes. I have tried to add new element as I added attribute before, but I get this error:
  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'

Here is my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode root = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "GeneratorXml", null);
doc.AppendChild(root);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TableData> td in this.tableDataList)
{
  XmlElement table = doc.CreateElement("Table");
  XElement name = doc.CreateElement("name", td.Key);
  // table.SetAttribute("name", td.Key);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have a read of [ask], then come back and provide a [MCVE] that describes your issue and allows us to formulate an answer.

Comment: Please be aware that XML attributes and elements have different semantics (attributes are unique, unordered, non-hierarchical. Elements are heterogenious, ordered, and hierarchical). You cannot, in general, convert between them.

Comment: Thanks. How do I implement only elements in Xml? I have been reading about XML but got confused over XElement to XmlElement.

Comment: `XElement` is part of the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace, whereas `XmlElement` is part of the `System.Xml` namespace.  You shouldn't mix and match the two - pick one or the other and use it consistently.